# Query with multiple joins and sum function giving wrong total or sum

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Posted query retrieving all the relevant fields but the **`SUM(af_py_commission)`** function causing problem as in and it simply add an extra zero at the end and then on the right end.

e.g. if the answer is 45 it will give 450 and data format of the field is float else this query is working perfect....

I've tried a simple query with same function on the same field but without the joins so it work fine and give correct ans. Can anyone help what i'm doing wrong in this>??

```
SELECT f.af_id AS af_if
   , aff_cust_tbl.af_id AS cu_af_id
   , aff_payment_tbl.af_cust_id AS pym_cus_id
   , SUM(af_py_commission)
FROM aff_tbl AS f
INNER JOIN aff_tbl ON f.af_id = 2
INNER JOIN aff_cust_tbl ON aff_cust_tbl.af_id = 2
INNER JOIN aff_payment_tbl ON aff_payment_tbl.af_id = 2;
```

Comment: english and grammer mistakes are not desirable. Please rewrite your words.

Comment: Do you have af_py_commission as field in other tables as well? Try writing full name e.g. `SUM(f.af_py_commission)` if it belongs to table `f`(alias)

Comment: no its only in one table that is aff_payment_tbl but also tried sum(aff_payment_tbl.af_py_commission) but same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in inner join

try this:

```
SELECT
f.af_id                    AS af_if,
aff_cust_tbl.af_id         AS cu_af_id,
aff_payment_tbl.af_cust_id AS pym_cus_id,
SUM(af_py_commission)
FROM aff_tbl AS f
INNER JOIN aff_tbl as f2
ON f.af_id = 2 AND f2.af_id=2
INNER JOIN aff_cust_tbl
ON aff_cust_tbl.af_id = 2
INNER JOIN aff_payment_tbl
ON aff_payment_tbl.af_id = 2;
```

The edited line is

```
 INNER JOIN aff_tbl as f2
 ON f.af_id = 2 AND f2.af_id=2
```

Try this:

```
SELECT f.af_id                    AS af_if, 
       aff_cust_tbl.af_id         AS cu_af_id, 
       aff_payment_tbl.af_cust_id AS pym_cus_id, 
       Sum(af_py_commission) 
FROM   aff_tbl AS f 
       INNER JOIN aff_cust_tbl 
               ON f.af_id = aff_cust_tbl.af_id 
       INNER JOIN aff_payment_tbl 
               ON aff_payment_tbl.af_id = aff_cust_tbl.af_id 
WHERE  f.af_id = 2;
```

If It doesn't give right result try without sum and post analysis here...

Comment: above query give this error 1054...'                                   'Query : SELECT    f.af_id                    AS af_if,    aff_cust_tbl.af_id         AS cu_af_id,    aff_payment_tbl.af_cust_id AS pym_c...
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'f.af_py_commission' in 'field list'
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Comment: @user1578993 I am sorry i though `af_py_commission` was a column of `aff_tbl`, buit apperently it is not, i have edited the query

Comment: hi ankur,i've tried your edited query but it gives some totally different result so i then tried my own query but without sum() and in the result there are almost 10 duplicate of each field and it adding them all so i put GROUP BY but then its not adding fields **this the code that i use **`SELECT
f.af_id                    AS af_if,
aff_cust_tbl.af_id         AS cu_af_id,
aff_payment_tbl.af_cust_id AS pym_cus_id,
(af_py_commission)
FROM aff_tbl AS f
INNER JOIN aff_tbl 
ON f.af_id = 2 
INNER JOIN aff_cust_tbl
ON aff_cust_tbl.af_id = 2
INNER JOIN aff_payment_tbl
ON aff_payment_tbl.af_id = 2
;

Comment: so what i conclude is that i've a problem in sql joining concept but you really help me i couldn't found it without your help  as different queries you suggested make to think to above solution so thanks a lot **ankur** can you guide me or help me from where can i get advance level and to the point tutorial or knowledge about databases and sql basically according to the development point
again thanks a lot

Comment: @user1578993 You can first start with w3school tutorials http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp and then you can try Pl/SQL http://www.plsql-tutorial.com/, but also keep in mind you learn the most when you practice, so create databases and write lot of queries

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing the `GROUP BY` clause required if using an aggregate function. Try this:

```
SELECT
f.af_id                    AS af_if,
aff_cust_tbl.af_id         AS cu_af_id,
aff_payment_tbl.af_cust_id AS pym_cus_id,
SUM(af_py_commission)
FROM aff_tbl AS f
INNER JOIN aff_tbl
ON f.af_id = 2
INNER JOIN aff_cust_tbl
ON aff_cust_tbl.af_id = 2
INNER JOIN aff_payment_tbl
ON aff_payment_tbl.af_id = 2;
GROUP BY f.af_id
```

Comment: both queries giving same result with and Without GROUP BY